# Moving a button and then return the place automatically after 1 second

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working with wpf c# ,I have a button, I want to the button move a little to the right when i click on it and then after 1 second the button return to the place automatically,
my problem is when i click on the button nothing happen.
 Here it is my codes:

```
    private void yellowBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        yellowBox.Margin = new Thickness(185, 61, 0, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
        {


            yellowBox.Margin = new Thickness(140, 61, 0, 0);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }



    }
```

Comment: use animations for moving a control: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652184/what-is-the-easiest-to-animate-the-position-of-button-in-wpf

Comment: you can use Animation in xaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use a DispatcherTimer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfTest2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);

        }

        private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button1.Margin = new Thickness(185, 61, 0, 0);
            dispatcherTimer.Stop();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
            Button1.Margin = new Thickness(140, 61, 0, 0);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alan B Thank you so much for help, it work but it has a little problem,it work opposite, i will fix by self, i got the idea ;) .

Comment: I wouldn't go crazy doing this for many buttons though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the layout... you could be doing something like this to force the update after setting the margin:

```
yellowBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {}, DispatcherPriority.Render);
```

Or you could just make the dispatcher set the margin directly on the rendering thread (which would be needed on multithreading scenarios):

```
yellowBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(
          () => { yellowBox.Margin = new Thickness(140, 61, 0, 0); },
          DispatcherPriority.Render
      );
```

However it's just better to use animations which have their own thread and update the layout automatically

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but using animations is better in my opinion...

```
private void yellowBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    yellowBox.Margin = new Thickness(185, 61, 0, 0);

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        yellowBox.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => {
            yellowBox.Margin = new Thickness(0);
        }));
        yellowBox.Margin = new Thickness(0);
    });
}
```